# iOS language setting influences app default language

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

As a basic feature of an ios app developed with Xamarin.Forms, I want English as the default language, when the iPhone/iPad language setted by the user has not been found in the transalation resources. At the moment I have got two translation resources, one for English and the other for Italian language.

In the iPhone that I am using for develop the app I've got the languages preferences as showed in the image below, that influence the default language behaviour of the app.
The expected behaviour is that English is used as default language, but insted Italian has been used.

Is this behaviour correct?

In the *AssemblyInfo.cs*  file of my project I've got:

```
[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("en")]
```

And this is the *Info.plist* file

```
<key>CFBundleLocalizations</key>
<array>
    <string>en</string>
    <string>it</string>
</array>
<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
<string>en</string>
```

[image: The iPhone language setting]

Comment: How are you naming the resx files? If english should be the default then the english resx could be named something like *Resources.resx* and the italian *Resources.it.resx*. The should be picked by default then.

Comment: @Michal Diviš, yes the English file is Resources.resx and the Italian Resources.it.resx. If in the list of the image I change the order swapping English and Italian, then English will win as a default.

Comment: Ah I see. I can't think of a solution for that. iOS seems to be searching for other language resources based on the preferred languages order instead of falling back to english when french is unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

In [Technical Q&A QA1828: How iOS Determines the Language For Your App](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1828/_index.html), Apple describes how iOS selects a language to use in an app. The following factors impact which language is displayed:

The user's preferred languages (found in the Settings app)
The localizations bundled with the app (.lproj folders)
CFBundleDevelopmentRegion (Info.plist value specifying the default language for the app)
CFBundleLocalizations (Info.plist array specifying all supported localizations)
As indicated in the Technical Q&A, CFBundleDevelopmentRegion represents an app's default region and language. If the app doesn't explicitly support any of a user's preferred languages, it will use the language specified by this field.

For more information you can check this documents:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/localization/